# Compute least squares using java

Tags: java, least-squares

I am trying to find a java code to compute the least squares solution (x) in the Ax=b equation. 
Suppose that

```
A = [1 0 0;1 0 0];
b = [1; 2];

x = A\b
```

returns the

```
x =

    1.5000
         0
         0
```

I found  Class LeastSquares,

```
public LeastSquares(double[] a, double[] b, int degree)
```

but in the input both A and B  are one dimensional arrays, however, in  above example, A is a matrix and B is an array.

In Class NonNegativeLeastSquares

```
public NonNegativeLeastSquares(int M, int N, double a[][],double b[])
```

A is a matrix and B is an array, but the description of the class says that it finds an approximate solution to the linear system of equations Ax = b, such that ||Ax - b||2 is minimized, and such that x >= 0. Which means that x must be always positive.

I need a similar class as NonNegativeLeastSquares, however with out the x>=0 constraint.
Could someone please help me?
 thanks a lot.

Comment: Do not link to examples and code, post them here.

Comment: What is the class LeastSquares and the others? What is your actual question? Is this a programming question or a math problem? Please edit your question and consider reading [how to create an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: What does matlab have to do with this question?

Comment: @thegrinner The A\B is a example of a operator implemented in matlab, and at first I had some link to it. But others suggested to remove the link so the tag is not valid any more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [Apache Commons Math library](http://commons.apache.org/math/), specifically the [`SimpleRegression` class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is the answer.

Comment: Yay, SimpleRegression link is dead!