# Java Linear Regression not working

Tags: java, linear-regression

Let me start off by saying I am terrible with math. I do not claim to be an expert (or even an advanced) mathematician by far.

What I'm trying to do is take this output:

```
55,55
55,55
340,340
333,333
41,41
71,141
143,133
121,122
12,16
```

And from those values (x,y) produce the following:

```
Slope (b): 0.96112312980002
Regression line equation: y=12.280535000464+0.96112312980002x
Correlation coefficient (r): 0.98120789611439
```

I used this website to calculate the above values can be found [here](http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/correlation-coefficient/).
Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated. I attempted using a snippet for this on stackoverflow [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431914/calculating-the-slope-of-a-series-of-values), however the results are dismal. Can someone point me to a way of calculating these things via a library or even a class of its own?

The value i am most interested in is the **correlation coefficient**.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't understand the formula at the alcula.com link?

Comment: Pretty much, im not sure how to do the calculation better than the stackoverflow snippet i found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Commons Math class `SimpleRegression` does it all.

You use `addData()` to input the x and y values.
You use `getSlope()` and `getIntercept()` to get the equation of the regression line.
You use `getR()` to get the correlation coefficient.

It couldn't be easier!

Comment: you weren't kidding about how easy this is.. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apache Commons PearsonsCorrelation! (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/correlation/PearsonsCorrelation.html)